# Sets- An Informal view

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, set-theory

I'm studying Elements of Set Theory by Enderton, and I have a trouble to understand the informal view of sets.
To be clear, I understand that he designed a kind of hierarchy based by a set of such an atoms, and the higher level in this hierarchy defined to be the union of the previous level and the power set of it;

Vᵢ₊₁= Vᵢ∪℘(Vᵢ)

But what then!, how could something like that improve our view about sets, and what did he really mean by saying,

> A fundamental principle is the following: Every set appears somewhere in this hierarchy. That is, for every set a there is some β with a∈Vᵦ₊₁. That is what the sets are; the members of the levels of our hierarchy.

Comment: See [Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Comment: The basic idea is that we start from a "ground level" made of [atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) only (i.e. objects that are not sets) or, for version of set theory without atoms, made of empty set only.

Comment: The next stage is produced with the *power set* operations, and so on...

Comment: This "construction" is the best approximation to the mathematical universe of *sets* according to the axioms of current set theories (ZFC and NBG), in contrast to the intuitive view of naive set theory: sets are extensions of concepts (see [Comprehension principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension): for every concept there is the corresponding set of all and only those elements satisfying the concept), that was discovered to be inconsistent.

Comment: See also [The Early Development of Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/)

Comment: Simple explanation in [Shoenfield,'s *Logic*](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vl1ZDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), §9.1 Axioms for sets (page 238): "A *set* is a collection of objects. Since there are no restrictions on the objects which may be members of sets, it would seems that we can specify a set by specifying for each object in the universe whether or not that object is a member of the set. This leads immediately to Russell's paradox. A closer examination of the paradox shows that a set $A$ is formed by gathering together certain objects to form a single object, which is the set $A$." 1/2

Comment: "Thus, before the set $A$ is formed, we must have available all of the objects which are to be members of $A$. It follows that the set $A$ is not one of the possible members of $A$." 2/2

Comment: The cumulative construction described above has the advantage of satisfying the "restriction" that a set is available as soon as its members are available, and at the same time is very "rich" in terms of closure with respect to the "intuitive" operations with set: union, intersection, complement, power-set, separation, etc.

Comment: When you have finished Enderton's book, you may have a look at " More Precisely. The Math You Need To Do Philosophy". Also, there is an entry in Stanford Enyclopedia Of Philosophy on " set theory". But you would bettter skip the section and go on.

Comment: In set theory, one can be surprised by definitions such as : " what is a cardinal number? a collection of equinumérous sets" ," what is a natural number? an element of the set of natural numbers". Same phenomenon here : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/#UniVAllSet